# AMD Zen 2: Hyper-V nested virtualization inside libvirt/kvm on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, amd-processor, amd-ryzen

On an Ubuntu 20.04.1 server with AMD EPYC Rome 7282 processors, I have created a Windows 10 (insider build 21301) virtual machine using libvirt 6.0.0 (qemu 4.2/kvm).
Within that virtual machine I would like to enable nested virtualization (Hyper-V) in order to be able to use WSL 2.

The preliminaries: For the `kvm_amd` kernel module, the `nested=1` flag is set.
Also, `cat /sys/module/kvm_amd/parameters/npt` reports `1`.
Furthermore, in the libvirt domain configuration, I have enabled the following list of Hyper-V hypervisor features: `relaxed`, `vapic`, `spinlocks (retries=8191)`, `vpindex`, `runtime`, `synic`, `stimer (direct)`, `frequencies`, `reenlightenment`, `tlbflush`, `ipi`.

The furthest I got is that Windows' `systeminfo` complains about Second Level Address Translation not being enabled:

```
Hyper-V Requirements:      VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
                           Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: Yes
                           Second Level Address Translation: No
                           Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes
```

These are the libvirt configurations that I have tested without success:

| CPU model | explicitly set CPU features | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EPYC-IBPB | hypervisor: disable, svm: require | systeminfo: no Second Level Address Translation |
| EPYC-Rome | - | Bluescreen: EXCEPTION_ON_INVALID_STACK |
| EPYC-Rome | hypervisor: disable, svm: require | boots immediately into Automatic Repair |
| host-model | - | Bluescreen: HYPERVISOR ERROR |
| host-model | hypervisor: disable | Bluescreen: CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT or SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED |
| host-passthrough | - | stuck at boot screen |

In general, Windows supports to be a first-level guest in a nested virtualization setup on these processors (at least 1st-generation Zen processors, [source](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/virtualization/amd-nested-virtualization-support/ba-p/1434841)). So which CPU flag am I missing in the EPYC-IBPB configuration?

Is it at all possible to achieve what I want?